# Contador con reset diario Django

Tags: python, django, contador

Soy nuevo en Django (Python).
Estoy tratando de crear un código personalizado que se incremente diariamente

```
"DOC-DiaMesAño-incremento diario" 
DOC-07022020-1,
DOC-07022020-2, 
DOC-07022020-3, 
DOC-08022020-1.
```

Hasta aquí "DOC-08022020-" lo tengo resuelto, pero al crear un contador para incrementar, no lo logro.
Este es mi código:

```
# Primera parte del código
def Codigo():
  dato = str(datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%Y'))
  return (('COT-' + dato) + '-')

#Incremento Diario
def Contador_diario():
   ultimo_documento = Documentos.objects.all().order_by('id').last()
   fecha_updated = ultimo_documento.fecha_updated.strftime('%d%m%Y')
   ahora = datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%Y')
   contador = 0

   if fecha_updated != ahora:
       contador = 1 
   else:
       contador += 1
   return contador


#Código final
def Codigo_completo():
codigo_completo = (str(Codigo())) + (str(Contador_diario()))
return codigo_completo


# Mi Model
class Documentos(models.Model):

numero_documento = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, default=Codigo_completo)
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, llevo varios días tratando de resolver esto :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes dos probleblas con tu código:

1.En tu código tienes `Codigo_completo` como default de `numero_documento`. Significa que únicamente cuando creas un nuevo documento se llama la función.

2.En `Codigo_completo` al inicializar `contador` a 0. Independientemente de que realizes el `if` contador siempre sera 1. Lo que tienes que hacer es extraer el código del `string` de `numero_documento`, convertilo a entero, incrementarlo y usarlo en el nuevo código.

**EDIT**

Intenta algo asi:

```
# aqui obtienes la fecha del último documento
ultimo = Documentos.objects.latest('fecha_updated')

#comparala con la fecha actual (cheka los tipos de datos)
if ultimo == datetime.now():
    # si son iguales extrae el codigo de número_documento con una expresión regular
# de lo contrario es un documento sin número anterior
else:
    contador = 0
```

Estoy asumiendo que `fecha_updated` no se modifica en algún lado del código

Comment: Gracias por responder. 1.- lo pensé de esa forma por que necesito que el código se asigne al momento de crear solamente (¿tendría que considerar otro caso?) y 2.- no comprendo cómo hacer lo que indicas.

Answer (score 4):

(gracias loki)
Esto me sirvió mucho también https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665076/

Finalmente así funcionó el incremento:

```
def Contador_diario():
ultimo_documento = Coti.objects.all().order_by('id').last()
if not ultimo_documento:
    return str(0)
fecha_updated = ultimo_documento.fecha_updated.strftime('%d%m%Y')

ahora = datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%Y')
contador = 0

if fecha_updated != ahora:
    contador = 1
    return contador

numero_documento = ultimo_documento.numero_coti
numero_documento_int = int(n_coti)
new_numero_documento_int = n_coti_int + 1
new_numero_documento = str(ew_numero_documento_int)
return new_numero_documento
```

a alguien le puede servir.

Comment: y que tal si le agradeces con un +1, y le acepta la respuesta?

Comment: Sigo con esto... el código se genera correctamente pero no logro resolver aún lo que indica @loki en el punto 1. Porque si tengo dos usuarios conectados al mismo tiempo se genere el mismo numero de documento (lo que no seria correcto). ¿Cual seria la mejor forma de hacerlo, para evitar ese problema? (¿esta bien aquí esta pregunta?)

Answer (score 0):

Sigo con esto... el código se genera correctamente pero no logro resolver aún lo que indica @loki en el punto 1. Porque si tengo dos usuarios conectados al mismo tiempo se genere el mismo numero de documento (lo que no seria correcto). ¿Cual seria la mejor forma de hacerlo, para evitar ese problema? (¿esta bien aquí esta pregunta?)